# How could you say the following in a proper way?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am preparing a speech and I want to translate a sentence in a dialouge to english.

My translation is like this:

"As far as I can tell from working with you for a short time, you are a good manager"

or

"As far as I knew you during the short time we worked with, you are a good manager"

Could you tell what I am trying to tell in a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "tell" version, not the "knew" version.

The phrase, "as far as I know" is an idiomatic expression meaning:

- *I may not have the whole story, but from what information I have, I can say*...

Moreover, the phrase wouldn't be used with the word "you" tacked onto the end. You could say:

> As far as I knew, you were a good manager.

This means that you thought the person was a good manager, but there may have been other people who would disagree with you. Or, we could say:

> While I knew you, you were a good manager.

But you would not say:

> As far as I knew <strike>you</strike>, you were a good manager.

The phrase "as far as I can tell" means roughly the same thing, you omitted the "you," so but the version with "tell" works a lot better with the part that follows:

> As far as I can tell from working with you for a short time, you are a good manager

That all said, expressions like "as far as I know" or "from the short time we worked together" are qualifiers that cast doubt on the person's management abilities. If you want to laud the person, you should just say:

> You are a good manager.

The other parts shouldn't be used unless you want the reader to know that your experience is limited and therefore may not be accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Which one is better to say: "As far as I can tell from the short time we worked together, ..." or "As far as I can tell from working with you for a short time, ..."